# Does VS 2019 Designer have trouble with TabPage, UserControl, and TreeView?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I'm encountering three issues with Visual Studio 2019 (16.6.3) Designer for .NET Core 3.1. Are these Designer problems or set-up errors on my part?

1. `TabPage` - Controls I drop on a `TabPage` can't be selected or modified in the Designer. I can select them in the Properties panel and change things, but no mouse action in the `TabPage` works. (Exception: If a `Panel` is the only control on the `TabPage`, I can select it in Properties and then use the mouse to drag it out of the `TabPage`.)
2. `UserControl` - Designer won't even let me begin to create a user control. When I choose Add --> User Control in the project, I get nothing.
3. `TreeView` - I can put several root `TreeNodes` in the Designer and they work fine. If I add a child `TreeNode` to a root node, that root node vanishes (even from designer.cs file) when the project builds. (I have only tried this with checkboxes on the nodes, though I doubt that makes a difference.)

This is my first venture into a .NET Core app. Am I missing something?

Comment: Create a WinForms Project based on .Net Framework. The Designer support in .Net Core is a work in progress.

Comment: @Jimi - I had thought it was more mature than it apparently is. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnWhitmire, I suggest that you can report a problem in [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html).